# VB6: Can't do any logging with my ActiveX dll

Tags: logging, vb6, activex

I am trying to add logging to a dll that seems to be get stuck running.  I have tried simply adding a couple subroutines to log to a file:

```
Sub PrepareLogging(ByVal strAppName As String)
  Dim objFS As FileSystemObject
  Dim objFolder As Folder
  Dim objFile As File

  Set objFS = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
  g_strAppName = strAppName
  If Not objFS.FolderExists(strLOG_PATH & g_strAppName) Then
    objFS.CreateFolder (strLOG_PATH & g_strAppName)
  End If

  Set objFolder = objFS.GetFolder(strLOG_PATH & g_strAppName)
  For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    If (Now - objFile.DateCreated) > 60 Then
        objFile.Delete
    End If
  Next
  Set objFolder = Nothing
  Set objFS = Nothing
End Sub

Sub LogAction(ByVal strMsg As String)
  Dim objFS As FileSystemObject
  Dim objText As TextStream
  Set objFS = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

  Set objText = objFS.OpenTextFile(strLOG_PATH & g_strAppName & "\" & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & ".log", ForAppending, True)
  objText.WriteLine (Format(Time, "hh:mm:ss") & " - " & strMsg)
  objText.Close
  Set objText = Nothing
  Set objFS = Nothing
End Sub
```

The code will run, but it seems to just ignore all this logging functionality.  I know the code is correct, because it works in other dlls and exes where I've added the module with these subroutines.  I tried adding a basic command to log directly to the event log:

```
App.LogEvent strMsg
```

But that fails.  If I try to catch errors in the code with a Goto ErrorHandler section:

```
ErrorHandler:
  App.LogEvent Err.Number & Err.Description
```

The app completely fails, such that I can't even select any options after logging into the web service.  I know that the problem is not the application log being full, as it continues to have new events added to it.  Any suggestions or ideas on what is causing this would be greatly appreciate.

**EDIT**

I appreciate the good suggestions, but they did not solve the issue.  I did, however, determine that for some reason, it does not like the line:

```
Set objFolder = objFS.GetFolder(strLOG_PATH & g_strAppName)
```

If I remove that, as the part to delete old files, it works.  I'd like to have that in there, to prevent hundreds of logs files being piled up on servers everywhere.

**END EDIT**

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251264 could be connected to your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what it was.  After getting it partially fixed, I was able to log out errors when that bad line failed.  It was giving a type mismatch error, which I tracked down to it having multiple definitions for the folder object.  The fixed code looks like this:

```
Dim objFolder As Scripting.Folder
```

That resolved it.  Thanks for all input!

Comment: Oh, and I didn't fully resolve the event log portion of things, but I don't WANT to log things there anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It could be failing for permissions issues.  I would do the following, not necessarily in this order:

- Throw ProcMon on the problem.  It will quickly tell you if you are even trying to write.  It will also point out permissions issues.
- Start VB6 in Administrator mode if you are on Vista or Win 7.

Comment: I updated my question with some new information.  Thanks for the good replies though.